# How to avoid IN (Select...) subquery in mysql stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, subquery

I have a stored function that needs to do a `select ... from ... where foo IN (select ...)`

The problem is that, it's incredible slow compared to doing a simple `where = ...`

Since this syntax is know to be slow, is there any possible way to store the results into a variable and then use that variable in the `IN ()` condition instead? I don't know of a way to store a query with multiple rows into a variable.

This is the fast equality using a variable. (but wrong b/c it only does 1 value instead of multiple)

```
BEGIN

    DECLARE average DECIMAL(10,4);
    DECLARE skuAsin VARCHAR(30);

    SET skuAsin = (SELECT DISTINCT asin FROM inventory WHERE sku = aSku ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1);

    SET average = (
        SELECT  avg(unitsByDay) FROM (
            SELECT i.date, sum(units_ordered) as unitsByDay from inventory i
            WHERE
                i.asin = skuAsin &&
                i.marketplace_id = mid &&
                i.date between d1 and d2
            GROUP BY date
        ) as vel
    );

    RETURN average;

END;
```

This is the slow using `IN (select)`

```
BEGIN

    DECLARE average DECIMAL(10,4);

    SET average = (
        SELECT  avg(unitsByDay) FROM (
            SELECT i.date, sum(units_ordered) as unitsByDay from inventory i
            WHERE
                i.asin IN (SELECT DISTINCT asin FROM inventory WHERE sku = aSku) &&
                i.marketplace_id = mid &&
                i.date between d1 and d2
            GROUP BY date
        ) as vel
    );

    RETURN average;

END;
```

Comment: ' I don't know of a way to store a query with multiple rows into a variable.' - there isn't one

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
i.asin IN (SELECT DISTINCT asin FROM inventory WHERE sku = aSku)
```

try to use `EXISTS`.

```
EXISTS (SELECT *
               FROM inventory ii
               WHERE ii.asin = i.asin
                     AND ii.sku = asku)
```

(I assumed that `asku` was a variable, possibly a parameter to the procedure. If not qualify it with the right table alias.)

Create an index on `inventory (asin, sku)` to support it.

Another index to consider would be on `inventory (marketplace_id, date, asin)` for the outer query.

Comment: So I just tried this, EXIST is about the same time (~3s) as the IN operator. Using a variable in a stored proc is about 53ms. Really interesting idea though.